# Convert Apache Rewrite Rules (fb_comment_id=) to NGINX Rewrite Rules

Tags: nginx

Can someone help me convert the following rule (for Facebook's comments) from Apache to Nginx? Thank you

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} fb_comment_id=.*$
RewriteRule .* %{REQUEST_URI}? [R=301,L]
```

This is the result I would like to get.

From:
www.example.com/category/article-name/?fb_comment_id=*

To:
www.example.com/category/article-name/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To remove the query string from any URI presented to your server with an argument beginning with `fb_comment_id=`, you can use an `if` block with a `return` statement.

For example:

```
if ($arg_fb_comment_id) { return 301 $uri; }
```

Place this `if` statement within the `server` block. See [this caution](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/) on the use of `if`.